# How to override a C++ virtual method (not in an interface class) in C# via C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

For reference, this question deals with accessing the C++ NaturalPoint Camera SDK via C#.

I am trying to pass along the implementation of a virtual method from C++ to C#. The trouble I am having is that the C++ virtual method is not in an interface class and I am not able to change that. Here is the class declaration:

```
class CLAPI cCameraListener
{
public:
    cCameraListener()  {};
    ~cCameraListener() {};

    virtual void FrameAvailable();
    virtual void FrameOverflow();
    virtual void ButtonPressed();
};
```

The CLAPI is defined as:

```
#define CLAPI __declspec(dllexport)
```

I can't inherit from the cCameraListener class in a ref class since it isn't an interface class and haven't come up with any way to expose the virtual methods to a managed class. I also need to be able to register the listener which I talk about more below.

Here is the working C++ implementation for listening for frames:

```
// process frames as they arrive
class FrameListener: public cCameraListener
{
public:
  Camera *myCamera;
  FrameListener(Camera *cameraPtr)
  {
    myCamera = cameraPtr;
  };

  void FrameAvailable()
  {
    Frame *thisFrame = myCamera->GetFrame();

    // do something with the frame here

    thisFrame->Release();
  };
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  // startup camera
  CameraManager::X().WaitForInitialization();
  Camera *camera = CameraManager::X().GetCamera();
  if(camera==0)
  {
      // print an error
      return 1;
  }

  // set camera properties
  camera->SendEmptyFrames(false);
  camera->SendInvalidFrames(false);
  camera->SetVideoType(SegmentMode);

  // setup frame listener
  FrameListener *myListener = new FrameListener(camera);
  camera->AttachListener(myListener);

  // start the camera
  camera->Start();

  // while loop holding thread

  // clean up
  camera->Release();
  CameraManager::X().Shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

Here is some of the existing C++/CLI wrapper code:
Link: https://code.google.com/p/npcamerasdkdotnet/

```
public ref class MCamera{
public:

  MCamera(Camera * camera){
    this->camera = camera;

  }
  ~MCamera(){
    delete this->camera;
  }

  void        Start(){camera->Start();} 

  void        SetExposure(int Value){camera->SetExposure(Value);}          
  void        SetThreshold(int Value){camera->SetThreshold(Value);}        
  void        SetIntensity(int Value){camera->SetIntensity(Value);}

  // TODO - WRAP THESE METHODS
  //void AttachListener(cCameraListener * Listener);
  //void RemoveListener(cCameraListener * Listener);

  // other wrapped methods here...

private:
  Camera * camera;
};
```

Notice that within the MCamera wrapper class, the AttachListener method needs to be implemented and requires a pointer to the cCameraListener class talked about above.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++/cli pass (managed) delegate to unmanaged code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972452/c-cli-pass-managed-delegate-to-unmanaged-code)

Comment: @Hans: That other question doesn't have anything to do with inheritance or virtual methods, that I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not so hard you need to wrap the listener in the manage class something like that:

```
class CameraListenerImp;
```

/**
 * Managed Version of the listener which will be used by managed clients
 */
public ref class ManagedCameraListener abstract 
{
public:
        ManagedCameraListener();

```
    virtual void FrameAvailable() abstract;
    virtual void FrameOverflow() abstract;
    virtual void ButtonPressed() abstract;

    ~ManagedCameraListener();

    CameraListenerImp* GetUnManagedListener()
    {
        return _unmanagedListener;
    }
```

private:
    CameraListenerImp*  _unmanagedListener;
};

// Unmanaged to managed listener wraper
class CameraListenerImp : public cCameraListener
{
public:
    CameraListenerImp( ManagedCameraListener^ in )
    {
        theClass = in;
    }
    virtual void FrameAvailable()
    {
        theClass->FrameAvailable();
    }
        virtual void FrameOverflow()
    {
        theClass->FrameOverflow();
    }
        virtual void ButtonPressed()
    {
        theClass->ButtonPressed();
    }
private:
    gcroot < ManagedCameraListener^ > theClass;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ManagedCameraListener imp
ManagedCameraListener::ManagedCameraListener()
{
    _unmanagedListener = new CameraListenerImp( this );
}

ManagedCameraListener::~ManagedCameraListener()
{
    delete _unmanagedListener;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ManagedCameraListener imp end

public ref class MCamera
{
public:
    MCamera(Camera * camera)
    {
        this->camera = camera;
    }
    ~MCamera()
    {
        delete this->camera;
    }

```
    void AttachListener( ManagedCameraListener^ listener )
    {
            // call unmanaged version of the AttachListener
            this->camera->AttachListener( listener->GetUnManagedListener() );
    }

    void RemoveListener( ManagedCameraListener^ listener )
    {
            // call unmanaged version of the RemoveListener
            this->camera->RemoveListener( listener->GetUnManagedListener() );
    }
```

private:
  Camera * camera;
};

/**
 * Managed implementation
 **/
public ref class MyOwnManagedCameraListener : public ManagedCameraListener
{
public:
     virtual void FrameAvailable() override { /* do something hard */ }
     virtual void FrameOverflow() override { /* do something hard */ }
     virtual void ButtonPressed() override { /* do something hard */ }
};

int main(array ^args)
{
    MCamera^ cam = gcnew MCamera( camera );
    MyOwnManagedCameraListener^ listener = gcnew MyOwnManagedCameraListener();

cam->AttachListener( listener );
cam->RemoveListener( listener );
return 0;

}

Comment: This works wonderfully, thanks Sasha! I'll pass this link along to the NaturalPoint forum and I'm sure the folks there will benefit from it as well. Thanks again!