# C++ to C# event handling

Tags: c#, c++, event-handling, c++-cli

So I've got my **C#** WinForm Application, from it I call my **C++ CLI MFC dll** library.

But there are some **events** on my C++ library, even this events happens in native (non-CLI) part of this library. And I need to call some code from my C# application and get some data maybe right there on this event.

so when this native function is called from client side :

```
bool __stdcall ClassName::WorkQuery()
{
         ......
        switch(pp->code)
        {
        case READCOMPLEX:
                       ..........
```

I need to bring the Data from C# **so I need to register this as event somehow.**

Comment: What do your events look like?  I thought events were a .Net thing, not a C++ thing...  Do you have any example code signatures you can share?

Comment: So my native C++ part works alike running server (it's even not my code) and there are standard C++ function which is calling when client is asking for some data.

Comment: So then what do you mean by "event"?  Is this a public property of some sort that is supposed to work like an event?  If so, can you share the signature of it?  Or do you just want somehow to find out when a certain C++ function gets called (internally)?

Comment: I just want to call C# part from this function without handling this function itself, I even not sure if that is possible to handle native C++ function. I called it even just because it happens in random time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++/cli pass (managed) delegate to unmanaged code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972452/c-cli-pass-managed-delegate-to-unmanaged-code)

Comment: So do you want to call C++ code from C# or C# code from C++????

Comment: C# from C++ but it's better description on question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is you need to run C# code in response to MFC event (or C++ callback), right?

Why can't you just register a native handler to the native event/callback, which then just invokes a .NET event, which can be the consumed from C#.

Comment: +1; This answer seems plausibly like a good solution.  Maybe a code sample is in order

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .NET event from the C++/CLI event handle, and then use it natively. Just use EventWaitHandle or the derived AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent.

Comment: no, I already got a function, which is called when something happened, how can I append event to it ?

Comment: You're confusing events with events. In the unmanaged, WIN32 world, the event is the notification that something has happened, not to be confused with the C# "event" object. The EventWaitHandle is a C# version of the WIN32 event, and can be used to listen to the original event and then call your C# "event".

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I'm pretty sure you're the one confusing events with events.  Nothing about this question has any requirement for a kernel event.