# how to pass a callback function from the c# code into a function in C++ CLR?

Tags: c#, c++, callback, clr, unmanaged

how to pass a callback function from the c# code into a function in C++ CLR ?
If I add a parameter to the callback function once it becomes invisible to my code in c#

```
//c++ clr
typedef int (__stdcall * Callback)(int*, int,int);

bool Init() //<-- OK
{
}

bool Init(Callback cb)//<-- Init is not visible to my code in c#
{

}
```

I plan to call this callback from another thread.
I have experience with callback for unmanaged DLL , but for the CLR does not understand how to do.

Comment: if you use c++/cli why don't you just declare a delegate instead of C function pointer?

Comment: A delegate of `System.Func<IntPtr, Int32, Int32, Int32>` or similar

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++/cli pass (managed) delegate to unmanaged code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972452/c-cli-pass-managed-delegate-to-unmanaged-code)