# How to access a non-static method from a thread in C++ Using ref class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++-cli

I have a class which I would like to call from .net. I decorated the class as 'ref'. I have a non static method 'someFunc' which I am planning to call using Thread.

//In A.h I have the following code

```
include "afxwin.h"

include "msclr\auto_gcroot.h"

using namespace System;

using msclr::auto_gcroot;

namespace A

{

    public ref class A
    {

    public:

        virtual bool Func();

        A();

        ~A();

        virtual bool Connect();

    protected:

        DWORD WINAPI threadConnect(void* pParam);

};

public class AHelper 
{

public:

    auto_gcroot A;

};

}
```

In A.cpp I have below code

```
// This is the main DLL file.

include "stdafx.h"
include "A.h"
include "string"
include "sstream"
include "stdlib.h"
include "strsafe.h"
include "windows.h"
include "tchar.h"
namespace A
{

    A::A()
    {
        m_FuncHandle = mpsNil;
    }
    A::~A()
    {

    }

    bool A::Func()
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool A::Connect() 
    {

        AHelper* AHelper;

        m_retVal = false;
        AHelper = new AHelper();

        AHelper->A = this;

        HANDLE Handle_Of_Thread = 0;

        DWORD dwThreadId;

        //DWORD WINAPI threadConnect(void* pParam);

        //If I declare the function declaration here I am getting

        //error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __stdcall  threadConnect(void *)" (?threadConnect@@YGKPAX@Z)

        Handle_Of_Thread = CreateThread (NULL, 0, threadConnect, AHelper, 0, &dwThreadId);   // with this code I am getting

        //error C3867: 'A::A::threadConnect': function call missing argument list; use '&A::A::threadConnect' to create a pointer to member


        return m_retVal;
    }


    DWORD WINAPI A::threadConnect(void* pParam)
    {
         AHelper* AHelper = reinterpret_cast(pParam);
         //Here I need to call Func
         return 0;   
    }



}
```

Comment: ref class means it's C++/CLI

Comment: ref class is managed class and is equivalent to class in Csharp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++/cli pass (managed) delegate to unmanaged code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972452/c-cli-pass-managed-delegate-to-unmanaged-code)

Comment: C++ standard doesn't support ref classes. C# is a .Net language which runs on the .Net CLR (common language runtime). C++/CLI is a language that microsoft developed to bridge C++ and the .Net languages, and it uses a C++-like syntax. CLI means Common language interface. That is what's you're using

Answer (score 0):

Use a managed [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx), instead of an unmanaged one, to call a method on a managed type.

```
gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &A::threadConnect));
```

and change the method declaration to match the expected signature of a managed thread.

```
void A::threadConnect()
{
    // No need for AHelper. The thread that's running will have a reference to
    // the 'this' object, so no need for a GCRoot to keep it alive.
}
```